# How to handle BroadcastReceiver session

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

I have an application that uses networking on about 5 screens (activities) and I would like to display a Toast message when the device loses internet connection. I created a BroadcastReceiver class to listen for changes in the network state, and display the toast accordingly:

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
            if (!Util.isInternetAvailable())
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connection lost!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how to handle the session for the receiver. i.e when to register it and when to unregister it. I tried the obvious, registering it **onCreate** of my main activity and unregistering it **onDestroy**. The problem with this is that the receiver is still registered even when the app is running in the background (since **onDestroy** only gets called when you kill the app). Alternatively, unregistering it **onPause** will cause the receiver to not be active when I switch activities. Is there any better way of handling this than simply registering the receiver **onResume** of every activity and unregistering it **onPause**?

Comment: Why you don't want it to be registered while your app is in background ?

Comment: Well that would make the Toast go off even when running other applications. If my app is in the background and the user loses connectivity, the Toast will be displayed even though I am outside of the app.